# Is there debug mode for the Xbox 360 Version of Portal 2?

Tags: xbox-360, portal

I see people spawn stuff like adhesion gel and stuff and I wondered If I could do that on the Xbox 360 since I only have the console version but I haven't seen any spawning in the console version but I wonder if you smart people know?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, With the Xbox, there is no option for a console menu.

Without a console, your xbox will not be able to have this function.
I mean you can try see if you can glitch your way around but I cannot
say that there is such an option.

Great game though :3

Answer (score -2):

Nope, "debug mode" is just a term made up by people who want to sound smart on the internet. "debug mode" is actually the console, which can be enabled on pc in advanced options, default is the ~ key to open it. Any commands can be run, in addition to spawning things, including noclip (fly through walls with ease) and others.
tl;dr: nope.

Comment: And how, exactly, can someone open this on the 360?

Comment: Well in Sonic 2 debug mode lets you spawn stuff if that isn't really called debug mode what is it?